# Windows 7: Search for all photos from a certain month from all years

Tags: windows-7, photos

How is it possible to view all photos taken from a certain month over the years?

What I need is to view all photos taken in a certain month (e.g August) all over the years. I have all my photos corrected metatagged with the datetaken attribute.

I tried searching using Windows Explorer search for photos with the Meta data 'datetaken' but I had to create another search for every month for each year.

Comment: I think it will depend on what you're trying to acheive here. It's a very interesting question but after the search is complete, what do you expect to have? A list of files in text format, or for those files to be shown in Explorer? +1

Comment: What is file extension of the photos? Or do different photos have different extensions?

Comment: @Dave i just need to view them in explorer.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with Explorer. A work around is to  copy the files (via a script) to a new folder (and remembering to delete them after)